# Curly brackets in Logic Apps parameters

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, workflow-definition-language

I've noticed that each time I'm using Azure Logic Apps Tools for Visual Studio (v2.11.15) and perform a Save, it surrounds some of the parameters in the josn file with curly brackets.

Eg, for a webhook, `"@triggerBody()"` becomes `"@{triggerBody()}"` and
`"@parameters('myKey')"` is updated to `"@{parameters('myKey')}"`

What is the difference between the two syntaxes? I've noticed a string encoding when the curly brackets are added, but is this to be expected when using braces?

Comment: Can you not whether or not this is causing any problems?  I suspect no because they're technically the same.  Just that the braces explicitly denote an object instead of presuming it.

Comment: I'm forwarding a JSON payload received on a Webhook (by using triggerbody mentioned in the question) and when the braces are added, it is re-encoded and tricks the clients.

Answer (score 4):

Expressions wrapped in `@{ ... }` will return a string and can be used in string interpolation.

For example, if your `myKey` parameter is the number 42:

- `@parameters('myKey')` returns `42` as a number.
- `@{parameters('myKey')}` returns `42` as a string.
- You could use it like this - `"favouriteNumber" : "My favourite number is @{parameters('myKey')}"`

There's more information about expressions in the [Workflow Definition Language Schema for Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-definition-language#expressions) docs.